# How to delete a LocalDB instance completely?

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I am using SQL Server 2014 Express and Visual Studio Community 2015.

When I used `sqllocaldb i` to list all localdb instances in my PC, I can see 2 instances, e.g. *MSSQLLocalDB* and *ProjectsV12*. I can stop and delete an instance by using `sqllocaldb stop MSSQLLocalDB` and `sqllocaldb delete MSSQLLocalDB`.

Then I deleted the folder *MSSQLLocalDB* under `AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\`, but when I run `sqllocaldb i` again, both localdb instances still exist. The problem is that when I launch VS2015, the deleted folder will be re-generated!

How can I delete the localdb instance from my PC completely?

Answer (score 2):

After you delete the instances like you have done with `sqllocaldb`, check if the auto-generated *.mdf* file in the project that uses the localdb still has that file in the folder `App_Data` and also make sure that you delete the correct database in the *Server Explorer*, i.e.:

1. Find in *Web.Config* the `<connectionStrings>` tag and check under `AttachDBFilename` property which file is being generated (you can also alter the name of the file in here and in order to change it's name completely, you can modify the `Data Source=(LocalDb)\ProjectsV12` field);
2. Go to the *Solution Explorer* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>);
3. Click on `App_Data` folder and in the top bar of the *Solution Explorer* click the *Show All Files* icon and then on the *Refresh* icon;
4. Delete the *.mdf* file in that folder;
5. Go to the *Server Explorer* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>);
6. Under *Data Connections* delete the matching database;
7. After this in command line use `sqllocaldb delete ProjectsV12` to make sure it's definitely deleted;
8. `Update-Database` in the *Package Manager Console* to regenerate the database (or the new instance, as you redefined in *Web.Config*).